# Orthographic Projection with OpenGL and how to implement camera or object movement in space

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I have made a cube with display list using GL_POLYGON.I have initialised it in the origin of the coordinates that means in (0,0,0).In my display function which is called in glutDisplayFunc I use the code:

```
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0,0,0,0,1,1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

I want to use orthographic projection using glOrtho.Well, my question is that: **Is it normal that I still can see my cube considering that my window size is 600x600?**

What's more, I would like some guidelines on how to move my cube or my camera with the relative OpenGL functions.Let's say I would like to move my camera back(to z axis) or my cube to the front(to -z axis).How can I do that?

Comment: There is nothing normal about your orthographic projection matrix. You are projecting an infinitely small space onto your image plane. You should not be able to see anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of you also need to set `glMatrixMode()` to `GL_PROJECTION` before you call `glOrtho()`, So it would look like this instead.

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

glOrtho(...); // Replace ... with your values

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

To move the sceen you can simply call one or more of the following functions.

- [glTranslate*()](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glTranslate.xml)
- [glRotate*()](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glRotate.xml)
- [*glScale**()](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glScale.xml)

You can click the above links to read how and what each function does. But basically:

- `glTranslate*()` translates/moves the current selected matrix.
- `glRotate*()` rotates the current selected matrix.
- `glScale*()` scales the current selected matrix.

You can also use [glPushMatrix()](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml) and [glPopMatrix()](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml) to push and pop the current matrix stack.

---

### Extra

*Also be aware that you're using old and deprecated functions. You shouldn't use them, instead you're now suppose to  calculate and create your own Matrix Stack.*

---

#### Edit

## Camera & Objects

Basically you do that by combining the above functions. Might sound harder that it actually is.

I will create an example of 1 camera and 2 objects, basically to give you the idea of how it works.

```
void render()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // The Camera Rotations & Translation
    glRotatef(camera_pitch, -1f, 0f, 0f);
    glRotatef(camera_yaw, 0f, 1f, 0f);
    glTranslate(-camera_x, -camera_y, -camera_z);

    // Object 1
    glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(...);
        glTranslate(...);

        // Render Object 1
    glPopMatrix();

    // Object 2
    glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(...);
        glTranslate(...);

        // Render Object 2
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

*Again replace the ... with your own values.*

The reason why need to translate the camera coordinates negatively is because why aren't *moving* a camera, we are actually "pushing" (translating, etc) everything away from the camera/center (Thereby the camera is in the center at all times).

**Important** the order in which you rotate then translate or translate and then rotate, is important. When needing to the camera transformations you always need to rotate then translate.

---

#### Edit

## gluLookAt ?

gluLookAt does 100% the same, like in my example.

Example:

```
// The Camera Rotations & Translation
glRotatef(camera_pitch, -1f, 0f, 0f);
glRotatef(camera_yaw, 0f, 1f, 0f);
glTranslate(-camera_x, -camera_y, -camera_z);
```

This is my own function which does 100% the same as `gluLookAt`. *How do I know?* Because I've looked at the original `gluLookAt` function, and then I made the following function.

```
void lookAt(float eyex, float eyey, float eyez, float centerx, float centery, float centerz)
{
    float dx = eyex - centerx;
    float dy = eyey - centery;
    float dz = eyez - centerz;

    float pitch = (float) Math.atan2(dy, Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dz * dz));
    float yaw = (float) Math.atan2(dz, dx);

    pitch = -pitch;
    yaw = yaw - 1.57079633f;

    // Here you could call glLoadIdentity() if you want to reset the matrix
    // glLoadIdentity();

    glRotatef(Math.toDegrees(pitch), -1f, 0f, 0f);
    glRotatef(Math.toDegrees(yaw), 0f, 1f, 0f);
    glTranslatef(-eyex, -eyey, -eyez);
}
```

*You might need to change the `Math.*` calls, since the above code isn't written in C.*

Comment: What about the camera? If I want to move the camera to the positive of z axis what function should I call?Let's I want to leave the cube at the origin of coordinates.

Comment: If I am not mistaken glTranslate,glRotate,glScale is for objects?Not just here in this code that you wrote, I mean everywhere.

Comment: Kinda, glTranslate,glRotate,glScale is for geometry tranformations. Thereby if why apply the reverse of the cameras x,y,z,yaw,roll,etc. before everything else it transforms everything to a point where it's like looking through the camera.

Comment: What if I want to move just the camera.I do not want to apply reverse things in these functions because I want to see how let's say gluLookat works.

Comment: @johnjohn `gluLookAt` works 100% like my above example. Take a look at edited answer, I've added how the `gluLookAt` function works.